# How to get image from the Wiki API on GitLab CE

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, gitlab-wiki

I'M using GitLab CE 10.4.3.

I wan't to integrate the Wiki from my projet in an external Portal.

I try with the API like that

```
GET /api/v4/projects/37/wikis/user-page-maps
```

and the response is

```
{
   "format": "markdown",
   "slug": "user-page-maps",
   "title": "user page maps",
   "content": "# MAPS\n\n## Profils ![maps](/uploads/602ef5895a99bf0512b43996f996fc5e/maps.png)"
}
```

I want to display the content **with the images**.
My front is on AngularJS with the directive `ng-showdown`. It's works well but, and it's normal, the image is not display.

Is it opssible to have an HTML reponse with linked images?
Is it possible to get the upload file with the API ?

In the other hand, have you an another idea to integrate the Project's Wiki on an external portal ?

Comment: Juste to add an information, if I parse the content's response and I change `/uploads/602ef5895a99bf0512b43996f996fc5e/maps.png` to  `http://gitlabserver/group/project/uploads/602ef5895a99bf0512b43996f996fc5e/maps.png` can't works because it's need an access_token th'at's why want to have the image with the API.

Comment: any ideas for this issue ?

Comment: Looking for this solution as well. Except you change the project visibility to public for wiki part at least, in this case, private_token is useless completely.